# C# limiting thread CPU usage

Tags: c#, multithreading, backgroundworker

Edited out : Originally stated two questions, tested one myself and got the answer.

I am creating a threaded reader/writer that looks over files in a folder set. It does this every 5 minutes, or less if a user specifies it.

My current issue is that the thread will look at the files with a tad too much voraciousness. I want to limit the thread to using at the most 30% of the CPU (or a user specified amount, in case they want it faster/slower). The reason for this is that this is a program that is supposed to be always on, and I do not want it to interfere with them browsing the internet or using other programs at the same time. I personally tend to note that threaded programs using 100% of the CPU screw with other programs even when they are set to a lower priority, and am trying to avoid this.

I was thinking of using PerformanceCounter to check the CPU usage, hopefully identify the program, and add more sleep cycles in if the performance (of the CPU as a whole, or my program in specific it finds it) starts to peak. I haven't found any documentation on limiting thread CPU usage other then "lol, why bother?", to "not really feasible" with no reasons why (which is perfectly ok - most people want the thread done ASAP and there may be no way to do this inherent to .Net or another C# library).

Does anyone know of a way other then setting it's priority lower, or adding more overhead by using PerformanceCounter/some other CPU monitor? Thanks.

Comment: Check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/482622/884410) answer

Comment: Are you sure your problem is CPU usage and not disk I/O?

Comment: @MattBurland - yup - just about to post that.  I've just been doing some 'optimum threadpool depth for CPU-bound tasks' investigation.  I have had 8/16/32/80/800 threads running on my 4/8 cores at 100% but, since the pool threads are set at 'THREAD_PRIORITY_BELOW_NORMAL', my browser etc. all worked just fine.

Comment: Thanks both of you, I'll probably give this a try then.

Comment: Makes me think...seems like there should be a special thread priority mode that keeps the CPU in its low power consumption mode. I bet even `ThreadPriority.Lowest` would step up the CPU's clock speed to its max.

Comment: Up to now no answer really fits the for this.

Adding system.thread.sleep(xx) would add to much of a wait on our new PCs with better CPUs and might only be enough for the older single cores we still have.

ThreadPriority.Lowest still boots the CPU to full for the duration but is my best solution at the moment.

Checking the CPU usage every cycle or two and adding more sleeps in is a bit of overkill and ineffecient.

No real answers, nor any I can think of, I'll mark the top as a solution since it will still help people down the line ^.^ Thanks all.

Why does it always get rid of my line breaks

Answer (score 2):

I'm unsure about how you are currently doing the folder watching, but I think you should take a look at the FileSystemWatcher class (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx).

You can set it up to watch a certain path for changes, and it's very light on CPU usage. It's also async (so you don't even need a separate thread).

Comment: Thanks, probably the best answer, but this is looping through a folder/txt database and would be file watching a large number of files and sub files. If it watched too high, well, I'd have the same CPU on issue every X time as normal. If it watched too low, then there'd be a million of them eventually.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if I understood you the right way. You check the files every 5 minutes and that checking (or their processing) takes too much CPU time off other processes?

If so, how about slowing it down by pausing inbetween processing (e.g. between files) using [`Thread.Sleep`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d00bd51t.aspx)?

I don't really think you should worry about some max CPU load (plus configuring this could be cumbersome or confusing for the user as for multicore CPUs it's not always clear on what 100% cpu use actually is, is it 100% on one core or 100% in total?).

The time to pause/sleep could depend on the amount of time passed so far and the amount of time left to do the other stuff, e.g. you could reserve 10 ms per file; if processing took 4 ms, you sleep for 6 ms.

If you're continuously checking the files for checking, ensure to use a `FileSystemWatcher` instead, which should solve your problems in this case.

Answer (score 0):

CPU load itself is not bad, as long as you do not max out.
You will be fine just by reducing the priority of the process. If there are other process with higher priority, they will be prioritized.

```
Process thisProc = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
  thisProc.PriorityClass = ProcessPriorityClass.BelowNormal;
```